# How to make stock quantity of another product decrease, when another product is bought?

Tags: stock, quantity

I am having trouble in finding ways of making other products quantity decrease, when a person buys a different item. This is because the item they buy will use quantities of other items listed.

Comment: If you are using for example a configurable product that will happen immediately

Comment: please elaborate your question by putting an example or demo in your question. This way you can improve your question and thus will get help from community

Comment: Also have a look at bundle or grouped products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event `checkout_submit_all_after`. That is dispatched when the order is placed.
Check all the products that are bought and decrease the qty for matching products.

```
public function checkoutSubmitAllAfter($observer) {
    $items = $observer->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();  
        $matching = ...insert your logic here for finding the products that need qty decresing...
        foreach ($matching as $match) {
            $stockItem = $match->getStockItem(); 
            $stockItem->setQty($stockItem()->getQty() - $item->getQty());
            $stockItem->save();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that using `save` in a loop is not the best idea. But it's better than nothing. You can make it work first and work on performance after that.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the methods in this observer: Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer

You should be able to use some of the events that this observer hooks into to accomplish what you want to with updating quantity of other products.